# Is it possible to convert a string into a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I have a string that stored in my database that is used as a custom layout.

I would like to parse their custom layout inside of my app layout, by using :

```
render_to_string(partial: custom_template, layout: "pdf_template", locals: locals)
```

Where `custom_template` is the string from the DB. However, when I try to do this I get :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

Is it possible to do what I'm doing? If so, what can I do to complete this?

I've noted that I can try things like this :

```
render_to_string(text: template, locals: locals, template: "pdf_template")
```

And

```
render_to_string(inline: template, locals: locals, template: "pdf_template")
```

But doing so, it suddenly can't find the template and returns :

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template layouts/pdf_template with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:pdf], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/elephanttrip/Sites/shasta/app/views"
```

Which is strange because it worked fine in its current location and definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your views in the database, you should use another rendering engine rather than in Rails by default. Check **liquid** gem (http://railscasts.com/episodes/118-liquid, http://rubygems.org/gems/liquid).

For example, we use this gem to render emails for our maillists (their templates are stored in the DB).

Comment: Yes I am actually using Liquid in this process. But I am trying to wrap "their" layouts with a global "wrapper" that is our layouts as well. I don't believe Liquid handles that.